# Should values in an array stack be dereferenced?

Tags: java, arrays, stack

Assume I have some stack implementation that uses an array to store the values. When popping, is it OK to simply change where my "pointer" value is referring to or should I set the current array location to null?

```
public T pop() {
    size--;
    return stack[size];
}
```

Versus

```
public T pop() {
    size--;
    T result = stack[size];
    stack[size] = null;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should set to `null`.

Comment: Why? Wouldn't a properly functioning array stack prevent the user from accessing popped values without setting them to null?

Comment: Your next `pop()` or `top()` will return the element underneath, but you've kept a reference to the object that was there before so it cannot be garbage collected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't set to `null`, the stack will still hold a reference to the object that was in the stack previously. It can lead to memory leaks because the garbage collector will not free the memory as long as something is holding a reference to the object.

So, set `stack[size]` to `null`.

Comment: Then should any array that is no longer being used in a program also be destroyed? The memory leak can only be the size of the array, and assuming I push a value after poppking, there is no longer a leak.

Comment: The memory leak is the size of what you are keeping in memory. If the object that is referenced at `stack[size]` is a big object, that may itself reference other objects, then it is a big memory leak.

Comment: Of course, if you push again, it will erase the reference. But who knows if someone is going to push? When you are writing a Stack container, you usually can not make any assumption about how it is going to be used. Of course, if it is only a toy implementation then it is not very important, but if you want to learn how to write that properly you have to defend against potential misuse.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should set them to null. Garbage collection is based on reference counts, and if you leave them on your stack, but inaccessbile (which is what you suggest by not setting null), the GC doesn't know that they are 'popped' off the stack.

Setting to null will allow the GC to do its thing